# Make all tabs collapsed in accordion by default within jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, accordion

I'm using an accordion widget in my WP based website footer and I want to make all tabs closed by default (now the first tab is always shown). Here is a sample of code of this widget (I copied it deirectly from the inspector panel):

```
<section id="presscore-accordion-widget-9" class="widget widget_presscore-accordion-widget wf-cell wf-1-3">
<div class="widget-title">Formationen der otmarmusik</div>
<div class="st-accordion">
<ul>
<li><a class="text-primary" href="#"><span>Title</span></a><div class="st-content"><p>Text</p>
</div>
</li>
<li><a class="text-primary" href="#"><span>Title</span></a><div class="st-content"><p>Text</p>
</div>
</li>
<li><a class="text-primary" href="#"><span>Title</span></a><div class="st-content"><p>Text</p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</section>
```

I tried to use some custom JavaScript

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true            
});
```

but it doesn't help and it occurs a new error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

So I have 2 issues:

- First. How to make all tabs collapsed by default.
- Second. How to use custom JavaScript function without any errors in
  WP.

---

**According to the *Vindhyachal Kumar's* answer, the solution was found by this code which works perfect**:

```
jQuery().ready(function () { 
setTimeout(function () { 
jQuery('.st-accordion li:eq(0) a').trigger('click'); 
}, 1000); 
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you actually have jquery set as a script source?

Comment: Yes it is. But I'm using the advanced option to add custom JavaScript. I mean I don't use source files to add this function. Maybe it cause this issue with JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code

```
jQuery('.accordion').accordion({
active: false,
collapsible: true            
});
```

Comment: This code returns me this error: `(index):254 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).accordion is not a function`

Comment: That means either element with class '.accordion' doesn't exists or required js file missing

Comment: May I use another function to make them collapsed? I posted the source code of this widget above.

Comment: can u share url of your page? will check it

Comment: it is password protected

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery().ready(function () { 
setTimeout(function () { 
jQuery('.st-accordion li:eq(0) a').trigger('click'); 
}, 1000); 
});
```

This custom jQuery code will solve this issue.